# Batch file:- Detect windows version and run exe file

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, exe

I want to detect windows version from batch and as per result start exe file

Sample code not working

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f "tokens=4-5 delims=. " %%i in ('ver') do set VERSION=%%i.%%j
if "%version%" geq "6.2" goto netfx_4
if "%version%" == "6.1" goto netfx_35
if "%version%" == "6.0" goto netfx_35

:netfx_35
 start "C:\Users\Ankur\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories\Notepad.lnk"
exit 1
goto :EOF

:netfx_4
start "C:\Users\Ankur\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories\Notepad.lnk"
exit 1
goto :EOF

endlocal
```

> for testing on place of exe i start notepad file

but this code is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f "tokens=4-5 delims=. " %%i in ('ver') do set VERSION=%%i.%%j
if "%version%" geq "6.2" goto netfx_4
if "%version%" == "6.1" goto netfx_35
if "%version%" == "6.0" goto netfx_35

:netfx_35
 start start "" name.exe
exit 1
goto :EOF

:netfx_4
start "" name.exe
exit 1
goto :EOF

endlocal
```

Note:  - EXE should be o the same location of batch file

Answer (score 3):

`>=` is an invalid comparison operator. Try `geq` (others are `equ` `neq` `lss` `leq` `gtr`

Comment: hi I updated code but the same result not working just cmd opened

Comment: Please explain what happened. `not working` means "did not do what I expected" - what did it do? "just cmd opened" - no idea what you mean here. `exit` will exit `cmd` - if you simply want to return an errorlevel, use `exit /b errornumber` Will executing an `.lnk` run the executable on your machine (personally, I use `notepad` which is likely in your `path`) What version is being returned for you? Mine would return `10.0` which is less than any of your tests because the comparison is being performed as a string and `1` is less than `6`.

Comment: sorry get the issue exe should be on the same location

Answer (score 1):

As the versions you are looking for are OS which use WMIC, I'd go down that route, *(especially as the output of `ver` is technically the not the OS version)*.

```bat
@ECHO OFF

FOR /F "SKIP=1 TOKENS=1-2 DELIMS=." %%A IN ('WMIC OS GET VERSION'
) DO FOR %%C IN (%%A%%B) DO IF %%C GEQ 62 GOTO :netfx_4

:netfx_35
START "" "%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories\Notepad35.lnk"
GOTO :EOF

:netfx_4
START "" "%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories\Notepad4.lnk"
GOTO :EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will work from DOS/win3 up to win11 and ready for later versions:

```
@echo off
  rem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Microsoft_Windows_versions
  REM set errorlevel 1, to check next command
<nul find ""
  REM extensions: FOR /f; delayedExpansion: !varNm! value at exec time
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
if NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 goto :WinNew
:WinOld
  echo *** OLD OS: Can't enableextensions ***
  ver | find " 3." >nul
  if ERRORLEVEL 1 echo Win 3.x
  ver | find " 4." >nul
  if ERRORLEVEL 1 echo Win 9x
    rem for pre XP define SystemDrive=C:
  if "%SystemDrive%" == "" set SystemDrive=%windir:~0,2%
  ver
  goto :FIN
:WinNew
    rem extract ver content from within []
  for /f "tokens=2 delims=][" %%i in ('ver') do set winVersion=%%i
    rem extract winVersion and winBuild
  for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=. " %%i in ("%winVersion%") do (
    set winVersion=%%i%%j&  set winBuild=%%k
  )
  echo *** WinVer:%winVersion%; Build:%winBuild%
  set winx=0& set winv=0& set win7=0& set win8=0& set win10=0& set win11=0
  set win7up=0& set win8up=0& set win10up=0& set win12up=0
  if %winVersion%0 lss 500 goto :WinOld
  if %winVersion%0 lss 600 ( set winx=1& goto :okVersion )&  rem 5.x: 2000,xp,2003
  if %winVersion%0 lss 610 ( set winv=1& goto :okVersion )&  rem 6.0: vista
  set win7up=1&  rem w7 or later
  if %winVersion%0 lss 620 ( set win7=1& goto :okVersion )&  rem 6.1: w7,2008,2011
  set win8up=1&  rem w8 or later
  if %winVersion%0 lss 630 ( set win8=1& goto :okVersion )&  rem 6.2: w8,2012
  if %winVersion%0 lss 1000 ( set win8=1& goto :okVersion )&  rem 6.3: w81,2012r2
  set win10up=1&  rem w10 or later
  if %winBuild%0 lss 200000 ( set win10=1& goto :okVersion )&  rem 10.0 b1xxxx: w10,2016,2019
  if %winBuild%0 lss 300000 ( set win11=1& goto :okVersion )&  rem 10.0 b2xxxx: w11,2022
  set win12up=1&  rem future versions here...
:okVersion

echo .
echo . Windows Version: %winVersion%
echo . xp:%winx% vista:%winv% win7:%win7% ^>win7:%win7up% win8:%win8% ^>win8:%win8up% win10:%win10% ^>win10:%win10up% win11:%win11%

:FIN
pause
```